# How do I get horizontal scroll history navigation to work in browsers in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, chromium

I can't seem to get horizontal scroll-based navigation (back/forward) to work in any browser under Ubuntu 18.04. For example, in Chromium, the setting to control this can be found by pasting the following in your address bar: chrome://flags/#overscroll-history-navigation. However, modifying this setting appears to do nothing.

Horizontal scrolling works for moving the view on a wide page in the browser, so my touchpad doesn't have any issues.

Comment: I have found that in Firefox (not Chromium), I can sort of do it by holding down the Alt key while swiping on the trackpad.

Comment: Does this work on ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Checked it out, does not work for me in Ubuntu 20.04. Pull to refresh did work

Comment: Still not working in 22.04 (Wayland nor Xorg) please help